# Angular Material 2 theme not working in production

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have imported the theme CSS to my style.css in my project as below, just like how it was stated on the Angular Material website.

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

When I have it in dev mode, the styling works, however, when I build to production, the styling does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you capture your console tab and network tab

Answer (score 3):

Add this line into the styles array in angular-cli.json :

```
"../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add 
    `<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">`

in     `<head>`    section of index.html

OR copy the folder prebuilt-themes from node-modules/@angular/material e.g. to your /assets folder, then @import "./assets/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; in your css/scss file